# (Version5) The function 'ta.ema' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope

Tags: warnings, pine-script, pine-script-v5

thanks for taking the time to read my problem.

I have this warning in my console : The function 'ta.ema' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.

So you can see the image of the script I did, I tried different alternative and still have the same warning, also the label.new still doesn't appear[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KEWi.png) on my chart.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

try to use ta.ema before the beginning of the if loop and store its value in a variable, then use that variable everywhere

Comment: thanks , it works !!

Unfortunately, I still doesn't get the label.new to appear on the chart.

If you can help me with that too it would be very appreciated, I will answer to my question to give you the updated informations

Comment: you will have to check open[i] with ema[i] right , otherwise it will compare only the last bar's  ema with last bars open for each candle

Answer (score 0):

you calculate several times the same calculus
and that's not good programming

as said above : "put the ta.ema in a variable" on a level-1 instruction
then use the variable everywhere
so it's less time consuming.